# Get <li> value based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists, getelementbyid

I have the following example code:

```
<ul class="name_of_class" id="TEST">
    <li class="foo">1</li>
    <li class="boo">2</li>
    <li class="goo">3</li>
<ul>
```

When a specific `<li>` is selected, the class changes to whatever the name is, plus `sortUp` or `sortDown`.

Example:

```
<ul class="name_of_class" id="TEST">
    <li class="foo">111</li>
    <li class="boo sortDown">222</li>
    <li class="goo">333</li>
<ul>
```

I am trying to get the value of the actual text inside the `<li>`, but I keep getting undefined.

```
var li = document.getElementById('TEST');
alert($('#TEST').filter('.sort').html());
```

I tried using different ways but no matter what I do I can't get the actual value, which in this case should be `222`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: where you get `.sort` class name?

Comment: `$('#TEST').filter('.sortDown').html()` may be?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the `li` with either `sortUp` or `sortDown` by using the `[attribute*="value"]` selector,

> The [attribute*="value"] selector is used to select elements whose
>   attribute value contains a specified value.

```js
const li = document.querySelector('[class*="sort"]');
console.log(li.textContent);

li.style.background = "red";
```

```html
<ul class="name_of_class" id="TEST">
    <li class="foo">111</li>
    <li class="boo sortDown">222</li>
    <li class="goo">333</li>
<ul>
```

See [css attribute selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the classes have to do with your requirement to get the text of the clicked `li` element. Just set up a `click` event handler on the `ul` and then in the handler, check the event target to ensure it was an `li`, then just get the text of the event target.

```js
document.getElementById("TEST").addEventListener("click", function(evt){
  if(evt.target.nodeName==="LI"){
    alert(evt.target.textContent);
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="name_of_class" id="TEST">
    <li class="foo">1</li>
    <li class="boo">2</li>
    <li class="goo">3</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
alert($('#TEST').find('li[class^='sort']').html());
```

You will find a li element that has a class that starts with "sort".
You can see more of this selector [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

Comment: You have messed up quotes in `'li[class^='sort']'` - should be `'li[class^="sort"]'`, also avoid that syntax on attributes that hold multiple values (like class). All it takes is one to add another class to an element ans see the JS fail miserably.